# Add a background image to the end of a string of dynamic text, behind the text

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I need to place an image behind (or in front of - it doesn't matter) my h1 text, with it positioned so that it will always be a little to the right of the end of the text, like this:
[image]

I can't seem to get the background image to display either on top of or behind the text. What am I missing?

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50f111c8e4b02b3b2218af91/t/5d9fa26b176671739c726240/1570742891482/CRMC-2020-Measure-h1-1a.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: -85px 12px;
  background-size: 32%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic Headline</h1>
```

With `:after`, I can't get the image to display behind or above the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to shift the background to display on top of the text, instead of the `background-position` you're looking for `margin-left`. Note, however, that you can't apply `margin-bottom` to an absolutely-positioned element, so you'll still need to make use of `background-position` to adjust the vertical offset. I've changed this to `4px` in the following example:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50f111c8e4b02b3b2218af91/t/5d9fa26b176671739c726240/1570742891482/CRMC-2020-Measure-h1-1a.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 32%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -85px;
  background-position: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic Headline</h1>
```

Comment: `margin-left` is the key. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the text with a span, that has left and right padding, and then put the image as the background of the span, and position it to the right:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  padding: 0 1.3em;
  background: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50f111c8e4b02b3b2218af91/t/5d9fa26b176671739c726240/1570742891482/CRMC-2020-Measure-h1-1a.png") right top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Dynamic Headline</span>
</h1>
```

And the same idea without a `span`, but not supported by IE/Edge due to `width: content-fit`.

```css
h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.3em;
  background: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50f111c8e4b02b3b2218af91/t/5d9fa26b176671739c726240/1570742891482/CRMC-2020-Measure-h1-1a.png") right top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dynamic Headline</h1>
```

Comment: This would be a good solution, although I'm trying to avoid having to add spans to all of my h1.

Comment: I've added another solution without a `span`.